# Would it be possible for an animal to develop pneumatic muscles through evolution?

Tags: science-based, biology, xenobiology

I have been pondering the question of how make animals stronger in unusual ways. It was during this process that it occurred to me: "Can living things naturally develop pneumatic muscle systems?" For this example we shall assume the creature is using a form of bio-organic fuel combustion engine to power the air compressor.

The idea is that the creature in question has muscles around 10 times as strong as normal for its size,relying upon the air compressor in its body. This would provide some unique challenges, namely in diet and also bodily composition.

Please let me know your thoughts on this,thank you.

Comment: You're asking what we call a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868), which isn't a good fit for our site.  [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110). To that end, I strongly recommend you reformat your question to be part of our [Anatomically Correct series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797) and go out of your way to meet the requirements specified for participation (in other words, you can't simply rename this post).

Comment: We already burn our what we eat to power our muscles, that's why Oxygen is a vital gas.

Comment: Improving strength in the "usual" way is already going to be hard if you want any magnitude of strength.

Comment: Very well. I suppose I will have to withdraw and reformat unfortunately.

Comment: *"relying upon the air compressor in its body"*. Ummm, that is circular. What powers the compressor - hydraulic muscles?

Comment: Well chasly I have edited it. Originally this question was very different. So confusion is normal and so is me having to edit it. So yes,hydraulic muscle is the assumed answer now.

Comment: The problem with your question now is that something has to generate the pressure in the pneumatics to begin with. So a hydraulic muscle (?) needs to build up air-pressure somewhere, this pressure can then be released to actuate the pneumatics. Another problem is that the generation of pneumatic pressure takes time or the hydraulic muscles would be the one's providing force. So movement is going to be limited to short duration efforts with normal muscles to. Additional problems are a stronger and heavier skeleton meaning more wasted energy and more food you need to eat meaning more movement...

Comment: Alas,I feel this question may need to simply be put down. Any advice?

Comment: @Jeremy Barrett - The idea of naturally evolved pneumatic muscles is  very interesting. I think you just need to formulate it better.   I think the best thing to do might be to delete the question then do some research of your own first. Make sure you have the facts right. Maybe give a simple diagram of the vital parts of the system showing how they connect and operate. Alternatively you could *flag* the question and ask a moderator to delete it or put it on hold. It's a good idea - it just needs some work.

Comment: Thanks chasly,I'll do that.

Comment: The question is now on hold, allowing OP to take all the needed time to refine it. Once the question will be edited it will enter the reopen queue, as it is standard process on SE. Due to the existing answer the question cannot be deleted.

Comment: You may also want to get your terms straight. Pneumatics uses the compression or evacuation of gasses to provide a mechanical force, hydraulics uses the fact the liquids cannot be compressed or expanded to guide mechanical force. Our muscles provide mechanical force by relaxing or contracting fibers through electrochemical means. A pneumatic power generator is, for instance, an internal combustion engine where the pistons are driven by expansion of hot gasses. Some of that power may be diverted to hydraulically operated valves for that same engine.

Comment: So originally this question was about a creature using a biological fuel combustion engine to power the pneumatic muscle system. That then had to be changed due to certain limits in regards to questions. (streamlining,too little to go on,asked if both pneumatic muscles and fuel combustion were feasible,etc)
The alternative to pneumatics would be dielectric electroactive polymers running off the engine instead. However that itself brought its own problems for features no longer listed.
As is,I have edited it once more. Pictures may be harder.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Biological Combustion would every work as the core power/fuel mechanism for any biological creature. Not only is combustion extremely destructive, the fuel would have to be very energy dense.

The biggest issue I see, is that there would be no way a biological creature would be able to maintain an environment or engine suitable for long term and consistent combustion. Combustion is hot, high pressure and destructive. You need energy dense fuel and something capable of withstanding that force for a life time. Ceramics are good, but unlike bone or antlers you have no way to repair a ceramic that has been damaged. One side has access to blood, veins and nutrients. The other side is subject to miniature explosions. So your ceramic engine heart needs to grow inwards to be able to repair itself and it needs to destroy itself fast enough so that there is still space for more the combustion to occur. This is of course ignoring that the ceramic shatters due to large impacts.

The next issue is that all of these materials are going to cost a lot of energy to produce unless your going to change the biology to something that isn't carbon based (and then its really whatever you want). Oil is extremely energy rich, and having the biological process necessary to create a spark for the explosion present from birth is going to be even harder. Your creatures are going to need a secondary digestive system just to be able to convert the wood, meat and whatever else they eat into the fuel required to power their muscles in the first place and a third system to be able to convert the wood, meat and metals into the ceramics required for your primary ceramic heart (engine).